# How to mock a regular method using Powermock

Tags: java, mockito, easymock, powermock

In groovy I am able to set the desired return value from a method to whatever I want in the test. Can I mock a regular method using PowerMock?

For e.g

```
int getYear() {
    return 2013;
}
```

In  the test can I set something like:

```
expect(getYear()).andReturn(2012);
```

//class underTest

```
class ProxyB {
    public X getDimensions(){
        GetResponseX getResponseX = client.newServiceCall().call().getResponseX();
        int d = getResponseX.getDimensions();
    }
}
```

I want to mock the part `getResponseX.getDimensions()` to return 21.

Comment: We need more details, if the method is static or final, you need Powermock. Otherwise Easymock will do the job.

Comment: it isn't static or final

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic code for mocking a simple call. Given the following class:

```
class Foo{
    int F(){
        return 42;
    }
}
```

You mock it by:

```
Foo fooMock = EasyMock.createMock(Foo.class);
EasyMock.expect(fooMock.F()).andReturn(41);
```

The problem in your case that you need to mock the entire chain of

```
client.newServiceCall().call().getResponseX()
```

For this you may need to change the way your class initially obtains a reference to `client`.
E.G, get it in a constructor or via a setter method. It might roughly resemble this:

```
class ProxyB{
    YourClient client;

    ProxyB(YourClient client){
        this.client = client;
    }

    public X getDimensions(){
        GetResponseX getResponseX = client.newServiceCall().call().getResponseX();
        int d = getResponseX.getDimensions();
    }
}
```

Now, when writing the unit test, you create a mock for `YourClient` and pass it to the constructor of the class under test. This way you have complete control over what it returns from within the method `ProxyB.getDimensions`. From this point you mock your way down the call chain (yes, it is a lot of mocks). Eventually, the `getResponseX` local variable should contain your mock and you can set whatever expectations on it.

Comment: But I'm testing the class that this method is defined in so I cannot mock the object